# Legend with both size AND color for colored proportional circles in ArcMap 10.7?

Tags: symbology, legend, arcgis-10.7

I want to create a map displaying several parameters, so I decided to use colored proportional circles in ArcMap (see image 1). I did this by converting my features to points and then choosing `Graduated colors` for one parameter (lake volume) and via `Advanced --> Size` (see image 2) I created an expression (`Sqr([Area_Mean])/500`) to display my second parameter (lake area) as the point size. The background color is the lake count.
However, when I try to create a legend, it gives me only the color ramp - the size parameter seems to get lost when creating a legend.
I have tried to create a dummy shapefile that displays just the size parameter - but as I have to use an expression to calculate the size (or else all points would be huge) I cannot just use `Graduated symbols`. Or is there a way to use an expression to adjust the size when using `Graduated symbols`? Then I could make that my dummy layer and create a legend for it...

What would be the correct way to create a legend for my data? I could have dummy shapefiles in my file that I don't display, I could alter the legend via `Graphic Operators` - if I just knew how to get the size parameter displayed.

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]